# How to run the lm() function multiple times with 3 columns per run from a dataframe of 12 columns?

Tags: r

I've a dataframe with 12 columns. For example, as below:

`values <- matrix(1:120, nrow=10)`

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12

1   11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81  91  101 111
2   12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82  92  102 112
3   13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83  93  103 113
4   14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84  94  104 114
5   15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85  95  105 115
6   16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86  96  106 116
7   17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87  97  107 117
8   18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88  98  108 118
9   19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89  99  109 119
```

Now, let's say I want to run a Linear Regression model `lm()` on a set of 3 columns each time (thus running the `lm` 4 times.. and each time giving a set of 3 columns as the dataframe for my each run of `lm()` function).

I was trying:
`tapply(as.list(values), gl(ncol(values)/3, 3), lm())`

and it said:

`Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data):
argument is not a valid model`

How do I solve this problem and run a linear model `lm` on a large dataframe by passing a specified number of columns as the input dataset for each run?

Comment: you want to run an lm on three cols at a time... of the 3 cols, which are the predictor variables and what is the response column?

Comment: I want to run an lm on three cols at a time, meaning i want those three columns as an input dataframe.. so 4 dataframes out of 12 columned dataset.. or a 5 dataframes out of a 15 columned dataset.. That's what I was trying.